# Magento 2 : Get current product id in product edit page

Tags: magento2, product, admin, catalog

**How do I get the current productId on the product edit page.**

**$request->getParam('current_product_id');**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
    $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
    $product_id = $request->getParam('current_product_id');
```

Comment: Have you tried with registry,
`<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
echo $product->getId();`

Answer (score 2):

1: Create one custom block file on your extension let said : `Blockname.php`

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Blockname.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;
 
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
 
class Blockname extends Template
{
 
    protected $_registry;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
 
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
 
}
```

2. Now, we will get the current product in your custom template phtml file like this one :

   ```
   if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    echo $currentProduct->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getName() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getSku() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getFinalPrice() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getProductUrl() . '<br />'; 
   }
   ```

**NOTE:** Remember, you custom block file must be set as block type of your phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `$objectManager`, but instead use repositories. If you still want to use the `$objectManager`, then do `$request->getParam('product_id');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in edit product page (BackEnd) i think param should be `id`. And should like this `$request->getParam('id');`